# I am getting "Index -1 out of bounds for length 17" error in WEKA, can you please tell me how to fix this?

Tags: attributes, weka, feature-selection

I am trying to run the 'glass' dataset in WEKA for Attribute Selector function. Here, I have chosen 'CfsSubsetEval' for the Attribute Evaluator Method and 'BestFirst' as the Search Method with default parameter values and I am getting the above mentioned error in the error log in WEKA. Can anyone help me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the class attribute for *BestFirst*.

Choose *(Nom) Type* from the combobox below the *Attribute Selection Mode* box and then click on *Start* again.